# Addition doesn't work due to AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which has 2 classes- A point and a circle:

```
import math
class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
         yield self.x
         yield self.y

    def __iadd__(self, other):
         self.x = self.x + other.x
         self.y = self.y + other.y
         return self

    def __add__(self, other):
         return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, tup):
        x, y = tup
        return cls(x, y)

    def loc_from_tuple(self, tup):
  #       self.x=t[0]
  #       self.y=t[1]
        self.x, self.y = tup

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def distance(self, self2):
         return math.sqrt((self2.x - self.x) ** 2 + (self2.y - self.y) ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
class Circle(Point):
    """Circle(center, radius) where center is a Point instance"""
    def __init__(self, center= Point(0,0), radius=1):
 #       Point.__init__(self,center)
        self.center = 1 * center
        self.radius = radius
 #       if not isinstance(center,Point):
 #           raise TypeError("The center must be a Point!")

    @property
    def center(self):
        return self._center

    @center.setter
    def center(self, _center):
        self._center = _center
        if (isinstance(self._center, Point) is False):
            raise TypeError("The center must be a Point!")

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self.center[item]

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Circle(
        Point(self.center.x + other.center.x, self.center.y+other.center.y),
        self.radius + other.radius)

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, center,radius):
        return cls(center, radius)

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
         if radius < 0:
             raise ValueError('The radius cannot be negative')
         self._radius = radius

    @property
    def area(self):
        """Calculate and return the area of the Circle"""
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        """Calculate and return the diameter of the Circle"""
        return self.radius * 2

    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle with center at ({0}, {1}) and radius {2}".format(self.center.x, self.center.y, self.radius)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})".format(self.center[0],self.center[1],self.radius)
```

The normal addition works as expected but the += does not. The following is the expected output.

```
circle1 = Circle(radius=2.5, center=Point(1, 1))
circle2 = Circle(center=Point(2, 3), radius=1)
id1 = id(circle1)
circle1 += circle2
print(circle2)
    Circle(center=Point(2, 3), radius=1)
print(circle1)
    Circle(center=Point(3,4), radius=3.5)
print(id1 == id(circle1))
    True
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/ayushgaur/Downloads/HW8_files (1)/shapes.py", line 206, in 
>           circle1 += circle2
>         File "/Users/ayushgaur/Downloads/HW8_files (1)/shapes.py", line 18, in **iadd**
>           self.x = self.x + other.x
>       AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'x

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Why does `Circle` inherit from `Point`?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to consider a Circle to be a kind of Point. And it breaks the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Circle(Point):` means that the class `Circle` is inherited from the class `Point` and therefore the function `__iadd__` of `Point` too. I do not see why you would want to inherit `Circle` from `Point`.

I would suggest removing the inheritance, i.e. having simply `class Circle:` and defining a function `__iadd__` for circle which is the function that defines what `circle1 += circle2` does.

Answer (score 0):

`Circle` inherited `Point`'s `__iadd__()` method, used when `+=` is called.

You may want to override the `__iadd__()` method by:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    return self.add(self, other)
```